# Windows Command Prompt Date with Single Digit Day & Month

Tags: windows, date, command-line

I'd like to create a folder like so:
C:\8_24_2013 (with single digit month & day)

The closest elegant example I found so far is this:

echo "%date:/=_%"

but it outputs this:
"Sat 08_24_2013"

I'd like it to look like this:
"8_24_2013"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the Windows Start menu type: windows powershell and then this one-liner creates the directory: new-item  -type directory c:\$(get-date -format M_d_yyyy)

Comment: Thank you for that as well! I prefer the powershell method.

Comment: @user814064 How do we get yesterday's date with the same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims== tokens= 2" %%i in (
  `WMIC OS GET localdatetime /format:value`
  ) do set localTime=%%i

set "YYYY=%localTime:~0,4%"
set "M=%localTime:~4,1%"
set "MM=%localTime:~5,1%"
set "D=%localTime:~6,1%"
set "DD=%localTime:~7,1%"

if %M%==0 set M=
if %D%==0 set D=

echo %M%%MM%_%D%%DD%_%YYYY%
```

Comment: Also, how would we use  LocalDateTime subtracted = dt.minusDays(1); to subtract 1 day to get yesterday's date?